# WTForms BooleanField treats JSON false value as true

Tags: python, json, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using `wtforms` to handle data from my post requests.  One certain post requests sends a variety of data including a boolean value.

My form looks like this:

```
class EditFileForm(Form):
    title = StringField('title')
    shared = BooleanField('shared')
    fileID = IntegerField('fileID')
    userID = IntegerField('userID')
```

I can see that when I receive the request the data looks like this:

```
data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
print(data)
>>MultiDict([(u'shared', False), (u'title', u'File5'), (u'userID', 1), (u'fileID', 16)])
```

You can see the boolean field is "false", and printing the raw data shows that too  However, when I print the actual form field I get true.

```
print(form.shared.raw_data)
[False]
print(form.shared.data)
True
```

I read that WTForms might not know how to handle false boolean values.  What is the proper way of doing this?  Using an `IntegerField` instead?

I have another form with a booleanfield that is handling false boolean values from my postgres database just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WTForms is not really meant to work with JSON data.  In this case, `BooleanField` checks that the value it received is in `field.false_values`, which defaults to `('false', '')`.  The `False` object is not in there, so it's considered true.

You can pass a different set of `false_values` to the field.

```
BooleanField(false_values={False, 'false', ''})
```

Or patch it for all instances by placing this somewhere before the field is used for the first time.

```
BooleanField.false_values = {False, 'false', ''}
```

You may better off using a serialization library such as [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle JSON data.